Need Url for Ajax request: Jodit Editor

I am trying to get Export to PDF working with Jodit, but for some reason I am running into this error above. The Documentation for the exporter features no code or examples nor can I find any at all.
  const [localConfig, setConfig] = useState({
    readonly: false,
    toolbar: true,
    fullSize,
    globalFullSize: false,
    extraPlugins: ["export-docs"],
    export: {
      fileProxy: "/export-to-pdf", // Ensure this endpoint is correctly set up on your server
      download: true, // Enable download directly from the editor
    },
    ...config,
  });

      <JoditEditor
        ref={editor}
        config={localConfig}
        onChange={handleWYSIWYGChange}
        value={value}
        {...props}
      />


Had the same issue and after some digging I managed to download the PDF by specifying the following configuration:

exportDocs: { ajax: { url: "https://xdsoft.net/jodit/finder/" } }

I'm using react@18.2.0 and jodit-pro-react@4.1.11.
Below, an example of working code:
import JoditEditor from "jodit-pro-react";
import { FC, useState } from "react";

export const DocumentEditor: FC = () => {
    const [editorText] = useState<string>("");

    const [localConfig] = useState({
        exportDocs: {
            ajax: {
                url: "https://xdsoft.net/jodit/finder/"
            }
        },
        license: "*****-*****-*****-*****",
        buttons: ["exportDocs"]
    });

    return <JoditEditor value={editorText} config={localConfig} />;
};

